# Why is the answer of $\frac{ab}{a+b}$ always smaller than the smallest number substituted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $\frac{ab} {a+b} = y$, where $a$ and $b$ are greater than zero, why is $y$ always smaller than the smallest number substituted?

Say $a=2$ , $b=4$ (smallest number here is $2$. Thus, the answer would be smaller than $2$)

$\frac{2\cdot4}{ 2+4} = 1.\bar 3$

I got this equation from physics. It's for getting total resistance and the miss told us to not waste time in mcq on it because the answer will always be smaller than the smallest number. But I can't explain to myself in words or by intuition why this happens. Any help??

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Are $a$ and $b$ positive?

Comment: I think you also need to assume $a, b > 0$ for otherwise $a = -2$ and $b = 1$ would be a counterexample since $\dfrac{ab}{a + b} > 0 > a$ in that case.

Comment: You're right! I'll edit it.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani:  I think this should be tagged [tag:algebra-calculus], not [tag:arithmetic], since it involves variable values, not only numerical quantities

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I guess you meant [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) but I'm not sure if that is very fitting either. In any case, I agree that `arithmetic` is not appropriate either. (The original tag was `abstract-algebra` which is why I changed it.)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani:  yes, I meant [tag:algebra-precalculus]; and I agree that [tag:abstract-algebra] is not appropriate for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to think about it:   Assuming $0<a\leq b$, divide the top and bottom of your fraction by $b$ to get

$$\frac{a}{\frac{a}{b}+1}.$$

$a$ is the smaller number and you're dividing it by a number greater than one, so the result is smaller than $a$.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b>0$ then $a<a+b$ and $\dfrac a{a+b}<1$ so $\dfrac {ab}{a+b}<b$.

A similar argument shows that $\dfrac{ab}{a+b}<a$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\frac{ab}{a+b}<\frac{ab}{a}=b$$ and $$\frac{ab}{a+b}<\frac{ab}{b}=a$$ if $a,b>0$

Answer (score 1):

Well, so long as $a,b > 0$ it's certainly true that $$ab < aa + ab,$$ but that gives us $$ab < a(a+b) \implies \frac{ab}{a+b} < a.$$

Similarly, $$ab < ab + bb$$ which gives us $$ab < b(a+b) \implies \frac{ab}{a+b} < b.$$

Answer (score 1):

For positives $a$ and $b$ let $a=kb$, where $k\geq1$.

Thus, $a\geq b$ and $$\frac{ab}{a+b}=\frac{kb}{k+1}<b.$$